# I am using dynamic forms to retrieve values from my form but I get undefined when I console log this object I create from the values in that form

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@ViewChild('studentForm', {static: false}) studentForm: NgForm
students: Student[];

updatedStudent ={
  Student_ID: 0,
  Student_Name: '',
  Student_Number: '',
  Student_Surname: ''
 }

onUpdateStudent(studentForm: NgForm){
this.editMode = false;
const updatedStudentValue = studentForm.value
console.log(updatedStudentValue)
const updatedStudent = new Student(
  this.updatedStudent.Student_ID,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Name,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Number,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Surname
)
console.log(this.updatedStudent)
```

}

When I console log updatedStudentValues I get a object of my students but when I try make a object for my Student model it says undefined Student_Name how can I fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
export class Student {
 public Student_ID: number;
 public Student_Name: string;
 public Student_Number: number;
 public Student_Surname: string;

 constructor(
Student_ID: number,
Student_Name: string,
Student_Number: number,
Student_Surname: string
) {
this.Student_ID = Student_ID;
this.Student_Name = Student_Name;
this.Student_Number = Student_Number;
this.Student_Surname = Student_Surname;
}
}
```

[image: my error]

Thank you for any help I am new with angular.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Stackblitz I am very new to all of this

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ You can create a sample application here so we can debug it and give you working code.

Comment: Yeah, but why is there component code in app.module.ts? Can you clean it and move the code to a separate component file?

Comment: Sorry this is wrong let me start a new one I was doing it fast

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtw9po

Comment: This last link is the correct one

Comment: Still not working- no environment in student.service.ts

Comment: The enviroment just holds my web API link it doesnt affect my problem

Comment: Then get rid of it. Create a minimal reproducible example that will give the same error that you're talking about in this post.

Comment: Ok busy making one sorry for the inconvenience I am new

Comment: Did you try `updatedStudentValue.Student_Name` instead of  `updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access `Student_Name` on the property `updatedStudent` which doesn't exist on `updatedStudentValue`.
Just access it directly as follows:

```
updatedStudentValue.Student_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

this.updated student is different from const updatedStudent. You should create object as below:

```
this.updatedStudent = new Student(
  this.updatedStudent.Student_ID,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Name,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Number,
  updatedStudentValue.updatedStudent.Student_Surname
)
console.log(this.updatedStudent)
```

using const updatedStudent, you are creating a new object which is block scoped and has no relation with this.updatedStudent

Comment: Had to change this.updatedStudent plus had to remove .updated student and it works!